# How can I write an SQL query that will checks if a column is zero it will update it and if its not, it will move to the next column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

To elaborate, I'm currently building an app that has people create an account and login. Their information that they provided is saved into my database. My database only contains one table which holds the users information. Each row is one user. Here's an image to give you a better idea:

[image: Image of my database]

The first six columns consist of the users information. However, in my app the user has an inventory which consists of forty slots, that is what the extra columns in the database are. When a node in one of the slot columns is equal to zero that means that the inventory slot is empty. However if it is any number but zero that means it has a specific item in that slot.

Now to get to my code, when the user clicks a button, a random method gets called which sets an int variable which is current named "i" to a specific number which is the ID of an item. At this point the user is prompted with two buttons that ask whether they want to keep the item or not. If they decide to keep the item I need it to be added to their inventory in the database. This is where my question comes into play. My app knows which user is logged in because when someone properly logs in it sets their username which is a primary key to a string variable which the rest of the app can user. so it knows which row to update but I need it to check through each column in order, and if it finds a column with a zero in the node, it will update it to what the variable "i" currently is.

This is my current code, I'm very new to SQL but I'm trying to teach myself, I apologize if this offends you (because it's so bad):

```
    try{
        //get connection to database
        Connection con = DataBaseConnect.getConnection();
        //create a statement
        PreparedStatement updateInv = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE userinfo "
                + "SET InvSlot1 = CASE WHEN InvSlot1 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot1 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot1 END "
                + "InvSlot2 = CASE WHEN InvSlot2 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot2 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot2 END "
                + "InvSlot3 = CASE WHEN InvSlot3 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot3 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot3 END "
                + "InvSlot4 = CASE WHEN InvSlot4 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot4 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot4 END "
                + "InvSlot5 = CASE WHEN InvSlot5 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot5 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot5 END "
                + "InvSlot6 = CASE WHEN InvSlot6 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot6 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot6 END "
                + "InvSlot7 = CASE WHEN InvSlot7 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot7 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot7 END "
                + "InvSlot8 = CASE WHEN InvSlot8 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot8 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot8 END "
                + "InvSlot9 = CASE WHEN InvSlot9 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot9 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot9 END "
                + "InvSlot10 = CASE WHEN InvSlot10 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot10 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot10 END "
                + "InvSlot11 = CASE WHEN InvSlot11 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot11 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot11 END "
                + "InvSlot12 = CASE WHEN InvSlot12 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot12 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot12 END "
                + "InvSlot13 = CASE WHEN InvSlot13 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot13 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot13 END "
                + "InvSlot14 = CASE WHEN InvSlot14 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot14 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot14 END "
                + "InvSlot15 = CASE WHEN InvSlot15 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot15 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot15 END "
                + "InvSlot16 = CASE WHEN InvSlot16 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot16 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot16 END "
                + "InvSlot17 = CASE WHEN InvSlot17 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot17 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot17 END "
                + "InvSlot18 = CASE WHEN InvSlot18 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot18 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot18 END "
                + "InvSlot19 = CASE WHEN InvSlot19 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot19 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot19 END "
                + "InvSlot20 = CASE WHEN InvSlot20 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot20 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot20 END "
                + "InvSlot21 = CASE WHEN InvSlot21 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot21 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot21 END "
                + "InvSlot22 = CASE WHEN InvSlot22 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot22 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot22 END "
                + "InvSlot23 = CASE WHEN InvSlot23 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot23 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot23 END "
                + "InvSlot24 = CASE WHEN InvSlot24 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot24 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot24 END "
                + "InvSlot25 = CASE WHEN InvSlot25 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot25 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot25 END "
                + "InvSlot26 = CASE WHEN InvSlot26 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot26 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot26 END "
                + "InvSlot27 = CASE WHEN InvSlot27 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot27 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot27 END "
                + "InvSlot28 = CASE WHEN InvSlot28 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot28 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot28 END "
                + "InvSlot29 = CASE WHEN InvSlot29 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot29 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot29 END "
                + "InvSlot30 = CASE WHEN InvSlot30 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot30 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot30 END "
                + "InvSlot31 = CASE WHEN InvSlot31 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot31 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot31 END "
                + "InvSlot32 = CASE WHEN InvSlot32 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot32 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot31 END " 
                + "InvSlot33 = CASE WHEN InvSlot33 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot33 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot33 END "
                + "InvSlot34 = CASE WHEN InvSlot34 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot34 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot34 END "
                + "InvSlot35 = CASE WHEN InvSlot35 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot35 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot35 END "
                + "InvSlot36 = CASE WHEN InvSlot36 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot36 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot36 END "
                + "InvSlot37 = CASE WHEN InvSlot37 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot37 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot37 END "
                + "InvSlot38 = CASE WHEN InvSlot38 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot38 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot38 END "
                + "InvSlot39 = CASE WHEN InvSlot39 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot39 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot39 END "
                + "InvSlot40 = CASE WHEN InvSlot40 = 0 THEN SET InvSlot40 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot40 END "
                + "WHERE userinfo.Username = '"+LoginController.userLog+"'");
        //process result set
        updateInv.executeUpdate();
        }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I know for a fact it needs work but I'm trying my best to explain my problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

P.S. I also apologize if the format of this question isn't quite right or proper, could you give me a few tips or tricks to improve my question asking abilities when it comes to this site? I'd like to stick around as long as I can!

Comment: Forty columns called "slots" does not seem like a good data model.  It should probably be another table called `UserSlots` (unless "40" is a universal constant).

Comment: There is a cap of 40 slots per user, they don't get anymore or any less, I was thinking about making another table for this but I concluded that this would make it easier.(again, I'm really new to SQL so my judgement isn't the best, any advice is helpful)

Comment: You should really make another table called `UserSlots`.

Comment: How would I link each user to their own inventory then? wouldn't that mean I have to have a table for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update users
    set InvSlot1 = CASE WHEN InvSlot1 = 0 THEN _something_ ELSE InvSlot1 END,
        InvSlot2 = CASE WHEN InvSlot2 = 0 THEN _something else_ ELSE InvSlot2 END,
        ..... the rest of InvSlots ....
    WHERE ... your condition what users to update ...
```

Comment: So I have a variable that is equal to the users username in the database, could I put that variable after "WHERE" to tell the database which row to do this in?

Comment: So I'm currently doing this in a java app right now, I would have all that code set to a prepared statement correct?

Comment: sure thing, make the query and send to server

Comment: I updated the code in my question to what I gather from your help, I still need to enter info for the then statement but does that look right for the syntax of this?

Comment: What would I put in the _something_ if I wanted to change what the zero to a variable named "i"?