# My SQL query runs properly but it doesn't seem to update the database as it should, does anyone have a solution?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

For some better context, I'm currently making an app that uses an SQL database. In this database the a row is equal to one user. Each user has an inventory consisting of forty slots. Each slot is a column in the database. What I'm trying to do is when a button is clicked, it runs this query which is supposed to check if an inventory slot in the users inventory is empty(its empty if its equal to zero). And if it is, it will update it to what the variable "i" is. But if its not, it will move to the next column and do the same process. However, when I run my app, it goes through the query but it doesn't update the database and there is no error. Does anyone know why?. Also, I'm still fairly new to this website so if I'm not asking this question properly I would love some tips or tricks to improve my questions for other users and to keep myself around! thanks!

My Code:

```
    try{

        Connection con = DataBaseConnect.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement updateInv = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE userinfo SET "
                + "InvSlot1 = CASE WHEN InvSlot1 = 0 THEN InvSlot1 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot1 END, "
                + "InvSlot2 = CASE WHEN InvSlot2 = 0 THEN InvSlot2 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot2 END, "
                + "InvSlot3 = CASE WHEN InvSlot3 = 0 THEN InvSlot3 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot3 END, "
                + "InvSlot4 = CASE WHEN InvSlot4 = 0 THEN InvSlot4 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot4 END, "
                + "InvSlot5 = CASE WHEN InvSlot5 = 0 THEN InvSlot5 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot5 END, "
                + "InvSlot6 = CASE WHEN InvSlot6 = 0 THEN InvSlot6 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot6 END, "
                + "InvSlot7 = CASE WHEN InvSlot7 = 0 THEN InvSlot7 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot7 END, "
                + "InvSlot8 = CASE WHEN InvSlot8 = 0 THEN InvSlot8 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot8 END, "
                + "InvSlot9 = CASE WHEN InvSlot9 = 0 THEN InvSlot9 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot9 END, "
                + "InvSlot10 = CASE WHEN InvSlot10 = 0 THEN InvSlot10 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot10 END, "
                + "InvSlot11 = CASE WHEN InvSlot11 = 0 THEN InvSlot11 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot11 END, "
                + "InvSlot12 = CASE WHEN InvSlot12 = 0 THEN InvSlot12 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot12 END, "
                + "InvSlot13 = CASE WHEN InvSlot13 = 0 THEN InvSlot13 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot13 END, "
                + "InvSlot14 = CASE WHEN InvSlot14 = 0 THEN InvSlot14 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot14 END, "
                + "InvSlot15 = CASE WHEN InvSlot15 = 0 THEN InvSlot15 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot15 END, "
                + "InvSlot16 = CASE WHEN InvSlot16 = 0 THEN InvSlot16 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot16 END, "
                + "InvSlot17 = CASE WHEN InvSlot17 = 0 THEN InvSlot17 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot17 END, "
                + "InvSlot18 = CASE WHEN InvSlot18 = 0 THEN InvSlot18 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot18 END, "
                + "InvSlot19 = CASE WHEN InvSlot19 = 0 THEN InvSlot19 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot19 END, "
                + "InvSlot20 = CASE WHEN InvSlot20 = 0 THEN InvSlot20 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot20 END, "
                + "InvSlot21 = CASE WHEN InvSlot21 = 0 THEN InvSlot21 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot21 END, "
                + "InvSlot22 = CASE WHEN InvSlot22 = 0 THEN InvSlot22 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot22 END, "
                + "InvSlot23 = CASE WHEN InvSlot23 = 0 THEN InvSlot23 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot23 END, "
                + "InvSlot24 = CASE WHEN InvSlot24 = 0 THEN InvSlot24 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot24 END, "
                + "InvSlot25 = CASE WHEN InvSlot25 = 0 THEN InvSlot25 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot25 END, "
                + "InvSlot26 = CASE WHEN InvSlot26 = 0 THEN InvSlot26 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot26 END, "
                + "InvSlot27 = CASE WHEN InvSlot27 = 0 THEN InvSlot27 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot27 END, "
                + "InvSlot28 = CASE WHEN InvSlot28 = 0 THEN InvSlot28 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot28 END, "
                + "InvSlot29 = CASE WHEN InvSlot29 = 0 THEN InvSlot29 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot29 END, "
                + "InvSlot30 = CASE WHEN InvSlot30 = 0 THEN InvSlot30 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot30 END, "
                + "InvSlot31 = CASE WHEN InvSlot31 = 0 THEN InvSlot31 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot31 END, "
                + "InvSlot32 = CASE WHEN InvSlot32 = 0 THEN InvSlot32 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot31 END, " 
                + "InvSlot33 = CASE WHEN InvSlot33 = 0 THEN InvSlot33 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot33 END, "
                + "InvSlot34 = CASE WHEN InvSlot34 = 0 THEN InvSlot34 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot34 END, "
                + "InvSlot35 = CASE WHEN InvSlot35 = 0 THEN InvSlot35 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot35 END, "
                + "InvSlot36 = CASE WHEN InvSlot36 = 0 THEN InvSlot36 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot36 END, "
                + "InvSlot37 = CASE WHEN InvSlot37 = 0 THEN InvSlot37 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot37 END, "
                + "InvSlot38 = CASE WHEN InvSlot38 = 0 THEN InvSlot38 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot38 END, "
                + "InvSlot39 = CASE WHEN InvSlot39 = 0 THEN InvSlot39 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot39 END, "
                + "InvSlot40 = CASE WHEN InvSlot40 = 0 THEN InvSlot40 = "+i+" ELSE InvSlot40 END "
                + "WHERE Username = '"+LoginController.userLog+"'");
        updateInv.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Complete");
        }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have more than 1 `SET` in a statement.

Comment: What would be an alternative to this?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I had a previous question about what I'm trying to do in this code, I got a answer that pointed me in the direction of this code, I'll link my previous question to give you some context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603309/how-can-i-write-an-sql-query-that-will-checks-if-a-column-is-zero-it-will-update

Comment: Read the answer again. It's very different from what you've posted here.

Comment: the problem is that the answer that was posted was written as it would be in an SQL IDE but I need to do this in java and I'm new to SQL so I'm a little fuzzy on the syntax for this.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could put the query into a variable and print out the variable.  Then the error would be obvious:

```
UPDATE userinfoSET . . .
```

As written, you need spaces.

Second, you should be using parameters to pass values into the query.

Comment: When you say I should be using parameters to pass values into the query, do you mean I should be declaring the column names and passing those?